# How best to fill classes with hierarchical data from a relational database in VB.Net?

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, class

I have some relational data in a SQL Server 2008 database split across 3 tables, which I would like to use to populate some classes that represent them.

The hierarchy is: Products -> Variants -> Options.

I have considered passing back 3 result sets and using LINQ to check if there are any related/child records in the related tables.  I've also considered passing back a single de-normalised table containing all of the data from the three tables and reading through the rows, manually figuring out where a product/variant/option begins and ends.  Having little to no prior experience with LINQ, I opted to go for the latter, which sort of worked but required many lines of code for something that I had hoped would be pretty straight forward.

Is there an easier way of accomplishing this?

The end goal is to serialize the resulting classes to JSON, for use in a Web Service Application.

I've searched and searched on Google for an answer, but I guess I'm not searching for the right keywords.

Comment: By hierarchical do you mean a tree data structure?

Comment: Yes, 3 levels (2 parent/child or one to many relations).

Comment: Wow, I've got to try this when I get a minute:  https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/producing-json-documents-from-sql-server-queries-via-tsql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of playing around, I've figured out a way of accomplishing this...

Firstly, create a stored procedure in SQL Server that will return the data as XML.  It's relatively easy to generate an XML document containing hierarchical data.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_test
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT
    1 AS ProductID
  , 'Test' AS ProductDesc
  , (
    SELECT 1 AS VariantID
      'Test'AS VariantDesc
    FOR XML PATH('ProductVariant'), ROOT('ProductVariants'), TYPE
  )
  FOR XML PATH('Product'), ROOT('ArrayOfProduct'), TYPE
END
```

This gives you an XML document with a parent-child relationship:

```
<ArrayOfProduct>
  <Product>
    <ProductID>1</ProductID>
    <ProductDesc>Test</ProductDesc>
    <ProductVariants>
      <ProductVariant>
        <VariantID>1</VariantID>
        <VariantDesc>Test</VariantDesc>
      </ProductVariant>
    </ProductVariants>
  </Product>
</ArrayOfProduct>
```

Next, read in the results into the VB.Net application using a SqlDataReader.  Declare an empty object to hold the data and deserialize the XML into the object using an XmlSerializer.

At this point, the data that once was in SQL tables is now represented as classes in your VB.Net application.

From here, you can then serialize the object into JSON using JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize.